# Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.Fragments.r: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Tags: android, fragment

I'm working on an issue discovered through Crashlytics, crash reporting service.

This app is using fragments.  My activity:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

When the super.onCreate line runs, I see this error on crash:

```
Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.Fragments.r: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Look close at what file it's looking for com.example.Fragments.r.  What the heck file is "r".  I do have a package named Fragments and have many fragment classes in there.  I don't have a file named r.java in the Fragments package though, nor have I ever tried to instantiate a class that would be in r.java.

Like I said this is a crash that Crashlytics found and I'm not able to reproduce it, but it is happening a lot.  Another funny thing is that the majority of crashes seem to be on Samsung Galaxy phones and the HTC One.

All my existing fragments are public and have empty public constructors, especially the ones called by this activity.

Thanks for your help!

db

Comment: @Egor Ugh, your probably right, checking now.  Crashlytics is supposed to convert those back over for me.

Comment: @Egor Put your comment into some sort of an answer and I'll select it. Your tip sent me into the mapping file and that directed me to not just the fragment, but a FragmentDialog overriding class I built in the fragment that has a populated, not empty constructor.  I bet when I clean that up, it will clean up the crashes.  Thanks!

Comment: Will do that and glad the suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"r" is probably the name of one of your `Fragment` classes after being processed by Proguard. And the issue may be that you didn't configure the Proguard correctly.

Comment: Your answer sent me into the mapping file and that directed me to not just the fragment, but a FragmentDialog overriding class I built in the fragment that has a populated, not empty constructor.  I'm making the constructor empty now.